# Get SharePoint Site Property Bag Values via Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

Is there a way to access SharePoint Online site level property bag values via Microsoft Graph?

Using Rest I can get it using this:

/_api/web/allproperties

I am not sure how to do the same using Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API documentation this does not seem to be possible.

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site

Comment: Thank you @Rune-Sperre